# Why is my Indesit dishwasher stopping mid-cycle?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, dishwasher

I have just moved into a flat with a Indesit integrated slimline dishwasher. It is all plumbed and wired in.

When I start the cycle the dishwasher pump starts working and then suddenly it stops and begins to beep. When I open the door, all four lights on the display are blinking at me.

I have checked the dishwasher filter and drainage hole. There is no blockage. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: If this is a rental, get with the managing office.  Google the brand name and look for a manual.

Comment: Having the model number would help _someone_ in searching for an owners manual which would probably give you a good clue what all 4 lights blinking (and what pattern, if there is one) means.